# ERROR: flask 1.1.2 has requirement Werkzeug>=0.15

Tags: airflow

I am trying to install Airflow on Ubuntu 18.04 by running the following command:

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

And I get the following error:

```
    OpenID Flask-JWT-Extended sqlalchemy-utils
ERROR: flask 1.1.2 has requirement Werkzeug>=0.15, but you'll have werkzeug 0.14.1 which is incompatible.
```

How can I resolve this error and install Airflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error, you are probably having a version conflict for one of the Airflow's dependencies: Flask requires Werkzeug module with a version >=0.15, but you have version 0.14.1 installed.

To avoid the problem, you can install Airflow into a Python virtual environment. For example, using pipenv.

Install pipenv into your user's install directory:

```
pip3 install --user pipenv
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin/
```

Install Airflow into a Python virtual environment:

```
mkdir my_airflow
cd my_airflow
pipenv install apache-airflow
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```
pipenv shell
```

Initialize the Airflow's database:

```
airflow initdb
```

At this point you should have a working Airflow installation. Notice, it is not a production ready installation, but it is enough to continue with [the tutorial](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/tutorial.html).